# Changing every set of 5 rows in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df$a <- 1:20
df$b <- 2:21
df$c <- 3:22
df <- as.data.frame(df)

> df
    a  b  c
1   1  2  3
2   2  3  4
3   3  4  5
4   4  5  6
5   5  6  7
6   6  7  8
7   7  8  9
8   8  9 10
9   9 10 11
10 10 11 12
11 11 12 13
12 12 13 14
13 13 14 15
14 14 15 16
15 15 16 17
16 16 17 18
17 17 18 19
18 18 19 20
19 19 20 21
20 20 21 22
```

I would like to add another column to the data frame (`df$d`) so that every 5 rows (`df$d[seq(1, nrow(df), 4)]`) would take the value of the start of the respective row in the first column: `df$a`.

I have tried the manual way, but was wondering if there is a for loop or shorter way that can do this easily.  I'm new to R, so I apologize if this seems trivial to some people.

"Manual" way:

```
df$d[1:5] <- df$a[1]
df$d[6:10] <- df$a[6]
df$d[11:15] <- df$a[11]
df$d[16:20] <- df$a[16]

>df
    a  b  c  d
1   1  2  3  1
2   2  3  4  1
3   3  4  5  1
4   4  5  6  1
5   5  6  7  1
6   6  7  8  6
7   7  8  9  6
8   8  9 10  6
9   9 10 11  6
10 10 11 12  6
11 11 12 13 11
12 12 13 14 11
13 13 14 15 11
14 14 15 16 11
15 15 16 17 11
16 16 17 18 16
17 17 18 19 16
18 18 19 20 16
19 19 20 21 16
20 20 21 22 16
```

I have tried

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{df$d[i:(i+4)] <- df$a[seq(1, nrow(df), 4)]}
```

But this is not going the way I want it to.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're missing a line at the top, `df <- list()` maybe? It doesn't run as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
df$d <- rep(df$a[seq(1,nrow(df),5)],each=5)
```

Comment: Beat me by 13 secs, although I would have used `transform`: `transform(df, d=rep(df$a[seq(1,nrow(df),5)],each=5))` (+1) anyway!

Comment: @Jilber Ah, I didn't know about that function. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use logical indexing after initializing to NA

```
 df$d <- NA
 df$d <- rep(df$a[ c(TRUE, rep(FALSE,4)) ], each=5)
 df
#--------
    a  b  c  d
1   1  2  3  1
2   2  3  4  1
3   3  4  5  1
4   4  5  6  1
5   5  6  7  1
6   6  7  8  6
7   7  8  9  6
8   8  9 10  6
9   9 10 11  6
10 10 11 12  6
11 11 12 13 11
12 12 13 14 11
13 13 14 15 11
14 14 15 16 11
15 15 16 17 11
16 16 17 18 16
17 17 18 19 16
18 18 19 20 16
19 19 20 21 16
20 20 21 22 16
```

Comment: The second line only makes three assignments (rows 6, 11, 16).

Comment: Not on my machine. I get 4 assignments of 1,6,11,16

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. I didn't notice the first one. But I meant that this does not provide the OP's desired output, if I understand correctly. "Every 5 rows" is clarified in the OP's "manual" section of the question.

Comment: Gotcha. Then I guess I need another `rep` step in there.

Answer (score 1):

And here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

dt[, d := a[1], by = (seq_len(nrow(dt))-1) %/% 5]
```